# How do i prevent playing multiple songs at the same time in my music player app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to build a music player app and I face problem when I try to play another song when a song is already playing.
I want my app to stop playing the already running song and start the new song.
I fetch the details of songs as a bundle from the adapter class into my songPlayingFragment. I tried implementing pause(),stop(),and release() methods. But none of them worked. I believed that I implemented them in the wrong section of code. 
This is my code without implementing any of the above mentioned methods.
Solution to this would be of great help. Thankyou.

Code of song playing fragment

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    audioManager = myActivity?.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    favouriteContent = EchoDatabase(myActivity)

    currentSongHelper = CurrentSongHelper()
    currentSongHelper?.isPlaying = true
    currentSongHelper?.isLoop = false
    currentSongHelper?.isShuffle = false

    var path:String?=null
    var songTitle:String?=null
    var songArtist:String?=null
    var songId:Long = 0

    try
    {
       path = arguments?.getString("path")
       songTitle = arguments?.getString("songTitle")
       songArtist = arguments?.getString("songArtist")
       songId = arguments?.getInt("songId")?.toLong() as Long
       currentPosition = arguments?.getInt("songPosition") as Int
       fetchSongs = arguments?.getParcelableArrayList("songData")

        currentSongHelper?.songPath = path
        currentSongHelper?.songTitle = songTitle
        currentSongHelper?.songArtist = songArtist
        currentSongHelper?.songId = songId
        currentSongHelper?.currentPosition = currentPosition

        updateTextViews(currentSongHelper?.songTitle as String,currentSongHelper?.songArtist as String)
    }
    catch (e:Exception)
    {e.printStackTrace()}
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    mediaPlayer?.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    try
    {
        mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(myActivity, Uri.parse(path))
        mediaPlayer?.prepare()
    }
    catch(e:Exception)
    {e.printStackTrace()}

    mediaPlayer?.start()
    processInformation(mediaPlayer as MediaPlayer)



    if(currentSongHelper?.isPlaying as Boolean)
    {
        playPauseButton?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_icon)
    }
    else
    {
        playPauseButton?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon)
    }
    mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
        songOnComplete()
    }
```

and my Adapter class

```
package com.musicplayer.echo.adapters
```

class MainScreenAdapter(arrayList:ArrayList, _context : Context): RecyclerView.Adapter()
{

```
var songDetails:ArrayList<Songs>?=null
var mContext: Context?=null

init
{
    this.songDetails = arrayList
    this.mContext = _context
}
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder
{
     val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
             .inflate(R.layout.row_custom_mainscreen,parent,false)

    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int
{
    if(songDetails==null)
        return 0
    else
        return (songDetails as ArrayList<Songs>).size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int)
{
     val songObject = songDetails?.get(position)
     holder.trackTitle?.text = songObject?.songTitle
     holder.trackArtist?.text = songObject?.songArtist
     holder.contentHolder?.setOnClickListener({

         val songPlayingFragment = SongPlayingFragment()
         var args = Bundle()
         args.putString("songArtist",songObject?.songArtist)
         args.putString("songTitle",songObject?.songTitle)
         args.putString("path",songObject?.songData)
         args.putInt("songId",songObject?.songId?.toInt() as Int)
         args.putInt("songPosition",position)
         args.putParcelableArrayList("songData",songDetails)
         songPlayingFragment.arguments = args
         (mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
                 .beginTransaction()
                 .replace(R.id.details_fragment, songPlayingFragment)
                 .commit()
     })
}
class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
{
    var trackTitle : TextView?=null
    var trackArtist : TextView?=null
    var contentHolder : RelativeLayout?=null

    init
    {
        trackTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.trackTitle)
        trackArtist = view.findViewById(R.id.trackArtist)
        contentHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.contentRow)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to create a single instance of Media Player and use is the application when you want to change the get media player instance and check it if the player already plays a song then stop the previous one and start the new one.

You can achieve this technique by creating a singleton class which has an object on the Media Player as a data member.

Answer (score 0):

just reset state of mediaplayer then play another song, here is an example:

```
  /**
   * release media player
   */
  private fun reset() {
    stopUpdatePosition()
    mediaPlayer?.isPlaying?.run { mediaPlayer?.stop() }
    mediaPlayer?.reset()
    mediaPlayer = null
  }

  private fun play(source: String) {
      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
      mediaPlayer?.run {
      isLooping = isRepeatOne
      setOnPreparedListener(this@AudioPlayerService)
      setOnCompletionListener(this@AudioPlayerService)

      // must prepare in another thread
      setDataSource(source)
      prepareAsync()
    }
  }

  reset()
  // source ~ http://xxxx.mp3
  play(source)
```